# add subdirectories to $PATH in bash using find

Tags: bash, find, path, string

I tried this

`PATH=$PATH$( find $HOME/scripts/ -type d -printf ":%p" )`

but it works only on Linux, on OSX (or Freebsd), it's not working because `-printf` is not POSIX. How can I write a compatible version for both platforms?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Do this for bash or dash shell:

```
PATH=$PATH$(find $HOME/scripts/ -type d -exec printf ":%s" {} +)
```

In addition, if you want to use fish shell, you could do this:

```
set -x PATH $PATH (find $HOME/scripts/ -type d -exec printf ":%s" \{\} +)
```

Comment: Good answer. `\{\}` can be replaced by `{}` though.

Comment: In some shells, fish shell for example, `{` and `}` have to be escaped. Escaping them in bash works too, although not needed, so it makes it easier to port. The question is tagged bash though, so probably `{}` could fit the answer just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged & title the Q with `bash`, here's a solution that doesn't require `find` at all -- it uses bash's [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) to recurse directories:

```
PATH=${PATH}$(shopt -s globstar dotglob; printf ":%s" ~/scripts/**/)
```

The shopt's run in a subshell, so they won't affect your running shell. The `printf` there is a bash built-in; I was careful to put the colon *before* the `%s` in the printf format string so that you don't end up with an unintentional empty path string at the end (equivalent to adding `.` to your PATH).

Comment: Some differences: that does not include the `$HOME/scripts/` directory instead and that includes symlinks to directories (and traverses directories when descending directories). Note that `$HOME` like that is `zsh` syntax. In `bash`, you need to quote the `$HOME` so it's not subject to split+glob (the problem was already in the OP's code). You could also use `~` instead.